# Short story about a boy who makes a virtual girl and updates her A.I as he grows up

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, artificial-intelligence

I am searching a free short story I found about 5 years ago on some book app on my tablet.

Basically in the story, this young boy got a computer (sometime during the 80s I believe) that had just enough RAM to be able to run a simple paint.exe type program, and he drew out this virtual girl out of pixels.

As the story continues, he's growing up and technology is getting better. He becomes able to make a small looping animation of the girl, then a basic program of A.I.

By the end of the book he has a wife (and kids I believe) and he hasn't taken out the computer he last programmed her on in 15-20 years, but then he does and it's still how it was.

Also, I believe the name of the virtual girl he made was *Sinclair*, but I could be wrong.

Comment: [*Sinclair?*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timex_Sinclair_1000) Cute name.

Comment: Wow! I am interested..

Comment: Why does he give his virtual girl a boy's name?

Comment: *"...he has **a wife** (and kids I believe) and he hasn't taken out the computer he **last programmed her on** in 15-20 years..."* Is his wife the AI program?